# Estimating a Size of Joining a Relation with itself

Tags: database, join, relational-algebra

I'm studying size estimation of logical query plans in order to select a physical query plan.

I was wondering what is the size of joining (natural join) a relation to itself?

e.g *R(a,b) JOIN R(a,b)*, say total number of tuples is 100 and attributes *a* and *b* both has a distinct values of 20.

Will the join size (number of tuples in result) equal to 100?

I'm so confused!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question as asked:
Natural join of a relation to itself is the identity operation; you'll get exactly the tuples you started with (yes, 100 tuples in this case).

The equivalent SQL for what you ask is:
SELECT R1.a, R1.b FROM R AS R1, R As R2 WHERE R1.a = R2.a AND R1.b = R2.b

This is because RA's (Natural) Join always matches by attribute name.

What could be more sensible? What's to be confused about?